# How can I display only resources from a specific year with getResources (Modx)?

Tags: modx, modx-getresources

I want to display only resources that are published in the year 2015.

I tried:

```
&where=`{"publishedon:":2015}`
```

But this is not working. Can anybody help me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

publishedon is saved as unix time in the database. So you have to convert your date (2015) to unix time and check a date range with that.

Create a snippet named **inyear** with the following code:

```
<?php
$year = $modx->getOption('year', $scriptProperties, '');
$where = $modx->getOption('where', $scriptProperties, false);
$where = is_array($where) ? $where : json_decode($where, true);
$where = ($where) ? $where : array();

if ($year) {
    $where[] = array(
        'publishedon:>=' => strtotime('1-1-'.$year),
        'publishedon:<' => strtotime('1-1-'.($year+1)),
    );
}
return json_encode($where);
```

After this you could call getRessources with

```
&where=`[[inyear? &year=`2015`]]`
```

You could even add an additional where clause with the &where property of the inyear snippet.

```
&where=`[[inyear? &year=`2015` &where=`whatever_else_where`]]`
```

Comment: Thank you. Unfortunately this is not working. with your code, still all my years are displayed

Comment: It should work, could you please call the snippet **inyear** directly ```[[inyear? &year=`2015`]``` and look for the output.

Comment: I called the snippet exactly like you said. There is no output

Comment: Sorry, i forgot to add the $scriptProperties in the getOption method call.